# Where to put JDBC drivers when using CDH4+Cloudera Manager?

Tags: jdbc, hadoop, cloudera, sqoop, cloudera-manager

I am trying to get JDBC jars recognized by Sqoop2 (CDH 4.4.0), but no matter where I place them, they do not seem to be recognized.

I have followed advice:

1. [here](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/cdh-user/xIBwvc_eOp0),
2. [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.1/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_14_3.html),
3. and asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618028/cdh4-sqoop2-and-jdbc-drivers-no-suitable-driver-found).

Can someone please provide a definitive answer to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend to follow the official installation guide for your Hadoop distribution and it's associated version. It seems that you are using CDH 4.4.0, but looking into CDH 4.2.1 installation instructions. Whereas in CDH 4.2.1 the JDBC driver jar files were expected in /usr/lib/sqoop2, since CDH 4.3.0 they are expected in /var/lib/sqoop2 instead ([documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_14_3.html)).

Comment: I eventually placed the driver in both the locations, but that is not what solved my problem. I did have to edit the `sqoop2-server` file in `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDHxxxxxxxxxxx/etc/default` since I use MRv1 rather than YARN.

Comment: I do not understand why did you had to change the sqoop2-server file, you are using parcels and therefore you are also using Cloudera Manager to manage your cluster - this kind of changes (MR1 vs. MR2) are automatically configured by CM when starting the services. Are you by any chance starting the Sqoop2 server on CM managed cluster without CM?

Comment: Nope. Used CM to start up Sqoop2, and couldn't spot a configuration to switch from the CM between MRv1 and YARN. had to go in and manually change the sqoop2-server file, and restart the service. Do you know where that configuration is in CM (a screenshot maybe)?

Comment: Thanks for your interest btw. I anticipate many more Sqoop questions, and your help will be highly useful.

Comment: You're welcome sir. CM is not exposing configuration to change MR implementation as that option is kind of given - CM already knows what implementation you are using, so there is no need for user to specify it again.